# PL/SQL sotred procedure won't execute in Java, but works in Oracle

Tags: java, plsql

I'm trying to call a PL/SQL stored procedure in Java. It works in SQL Developer. When I start the application nothing happens and I don't get any error messages. There are no changes in the database.

Here is the code:

```
try{
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl","student","student");


            CallableStatement callProc = con.prepareCall("CALL compare_images(1,2)");
            callProc.execute();  

            con.close();

            }catch(Exception e) { 
                System.out.println(e);
            }
```

Comment: Could you add the error you get from logs ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: sorry about that, that was a leftover.

Comment: Two ideas: 1) get rid of `CALL` in the statement string and make it `COMPARE_IMAGES(1, 2)` - I believe `CALL` is only used when invoking a procedure from SQL*Plus, and if that doesn't work, 2) try `BEGIN COMPARE_IMAGES(1, 2); END;` as the statement string.  Just a couple ideas to try.  Share and enjoy.

Comment: @BobJarvis: Thank you! Changing it to ("BEGIN COMPARE_IMAGES(1, 2); END;") solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

That should be:

```
CallableStatement callProc = con.prepareCall("{call compare_images(1,2)}");
```

(note the curly braces enclosing the actual SQL statement)

Comment: @user1477362: what is that stored procedure doing? What do you expect to happen? How do you know it doesn't work? Where do you commit your changes?

Comment: It compares two pictures, depending whether they are same or different, it will change a value in another table. This value is supposed to change but it does not. Although it works in SQL Developer.

Comment: @user1477362: I don't see any commit in your code. What if you select the changed rows from within the Java program - do you see the changes then? Are you sure you are passing the correct values? Are you sure you are connecting to the same database and user from within your program and SQL Developer?

Answer (score 0):

As it it mentioned in specification of [Connection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareCall%28java.lang.String%29) interface. Method `prepareCall(String)` first parameter is statement:

> Typically this statement is specified using JDBC call escape syntax.

The escape syntax for JDBC look like `{extension}` [(more)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs91/jdbc_drivers/sqlescape.html).